# Can lastpass automatically prompt you for password when Firefox is first launched?

Tags: firefox, login, lastpass

Is there a way to have Lastpass automatically prompt you for the master password when you open Firefox? Ideally I would like to enter the password once while the user account is still logged in, even if Firefox is closed an reopened.

The problem is saving the password is unsafe incase someone manages to get past the account login apassword and not saving the password is inconvinient as I have to remeber to click on lastpass and login each time I want it to log into a site for me.

Comment: You can't save passwords to lastpass unless you are logged into lasspass.  I don't understand the security concern.

Comment: @Ramhound that's not what I mean. I'm talking about the master password to log into lastpass. If that doensn't answer your question I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on Chrome (I can't imagine it being different for Firefox), click the LastPass icon and choose `Preferences` from the menu. Under the `General` tab, tick `Automatically Logoff when all browsers [...]` and set the number of minutes to `0`.

[image]

<s>To make Firefox prompt for your credentials at startup, pick a website that you've set LastPass to automatically log in, and leave it open as a tab.</s>

Next, go to the `Advanced` tab. Tick the `Open login dialog when browser starts` option, then click `Save`.

[image]

Comment: I don't follow the second part of your instructions. So I set the homepage to a page I use lastpass to automatically log in with. This doesn't force lastpass to prompt to log into iteslf.

Comment: @Celeritas Post updated. See if that helps.

Comment: Ok but if I close the browser and open it again I have to log in. Why did you say "tick Automatically Logoff when all browsers [...] and set the number of minutes to 0." shouldn't it be 30 minutes?

Comment: @Celeritas `if I close the browser and open it again I have to log in` - isn't this what you want? The latter part is set as such because those two settings are mutually inclusive.

Comment: what I want is if I close the browser but don't log out of the user account then when I open the browser again I don't have to log into lastpass.

Comment: Ok great it's working, last question: after I log in it opens up the lastpass vault in a new tab. Is there a way I can disable this? I always have to close this extra tab it opens.

Comment: @Celeritas I haven't seen any option to disable this behaviour. Good to hear that it's working for you though.

Answer (score 0):

@Celeritas To disable LastPass automatically opening the vault when Firefox launches, uncheck this box:

[image]